# drag and drop image from imageview1 to imageview2 on anchorpane

Tags: javafx-8

There are two imageviews on AnchorPane in scenebuilder .one imageview1 has image
and now trying to drag and drop on imageview2.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageview1;
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageview2;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        imageview1.setImage(new Image("File:///C:imagedragndropex6/IMG_4093.JPG"));

    }    
 @FXML
    private void handleDragDetected(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("DragDetectedEntered");
         // ImageView im=(ImageView)event.getSource();
                 Image img=imageview1.getImage();

           Dragboard db= imageview1.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
           // db.setDragView(imageview1.getImage());
            ClipboardContent content=new ClipboardContent();
            content.putImage(img);
             System.out.println(content.hasImage());
            db.setContent(content);
             System.out.println(db.hasImage());
            System.out.println("DragDetectedExited");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleDragOver(DragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("DragOverEntered");
        Dragboard db=event.getDragboard();
         System.out.println(db.hasImage());
            if(db.hasImage()){
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
                 System.out.println(event.getAcceptedTransferMode());
            }
            event.consume();
             System.out.println("DragOverExited");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleDragDropped(DragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("DragDroppedrEntered");
          Dragboard dragboard=event.getDragboard();
            if(dragboard.hasImage()){
                Image img=dragboard.getImage();
                imageview2.setFitHeight(200);
                 imageview2.setFitWidth(200);
                 imageview2.setPreserveRatio(true);
                imageview2.setImage(img);

            event.setDropCompleted(true);
            }
            else
            event.setDropCompleted(false);

            System.out.println("DragDroppedrEntered");
    }
}
```

output:

```
DragDetectedEntered
true
true
DragDetectedExited
DragOverEntered
false
DragOverExited
```

Plz let me know what is wrong with this trying for hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private ImageView imageview1;
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorpane;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    imageview1.setImage(new Image("File:///D:/Downloads/Earthpic.jpg"));
    // TODO
}    

@FXML
private void handleDragDetected(MouseEvent event) {

    System.out.println("DragDetectedEntered");



    Dragboard db= imageview1.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
    Image img=imageview1.getImage();

    ClipboardContent content=new ClipboardContent();
    content.putImage(img);
    System.out.println(content.hasImage());
    db.setContent(content);
    System.out.println(db.hasImage());
    System.out.println("DragDetectedExited");
    event.consume();
}

@FXML
private void handleDragOver(DragEvent event) {
    System.out.println("DragOverEntered");
    System.out.println(event.getGestureSource());
    System.out.println(event.getGestureTarget());
    Dragboard db=event.getDragboard();        
     System.out.println(db.hasImage());
       if(db.hasImage()){

            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
             System.out.println(event.getAcceptedTransferMode());
        }
        event.consume();
         System.out.println("DragOverExited");
}

@FXML
private void handleDragDropped(DragEvent event) {
    System.out.println("DragDroppedrEntered");
      Dragboard dragboard=event.getDragboard();
        if(dragboard.hasImage()){
            Image img=dragboard.getImage();
           ImageView imageview2=new ImageView();
            imageview2.setFitHeight(200);
             imageview2.setFitWidth(200);
             imageview2.setLayoutX(400);
             imageview2.setLayoutY(150);
             imageview2.setPreserveRatio(true);
            imageview2.setImage(img);
            anchorpane.getChildren().add(imageview2);

        event.setDropCompleted(true);
        }
        else
        event.setDropCompleted(false);

        System.out.println("DragDroppedrEntered");
}
}
```

Finally,this works fine...handleDragOver and handleDragDropped has to be set to anchorpane.